# How to view Windows desktops over network?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I would like to view a remote Windows desktop and also control the action/clicks, start applications, etc, from my Ubuntu desktop.

Can this be done? If yes, is there any easy to use tool for this?

Note: One remote machine is running Windows 7, and other is on Windows 8. My machine is running ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to control the remote machine along with remote user, like a remote assistance session in windows, the best solution for me was using teamviewer

Comment: Teamviewer is just the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Install [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/download/) server on the Windows machines, then connect to them from Ubuntu using Remmina Remote Desktop Client (select VNC as the protocol).

Answer (score 0):

If the machine is NOT Windows Home-based license, you can also use Remmina with RDP protocol (no VNC required on the Windows side). Only downside of this approach is the Windows machine will not be accessible from the machine itself during the remote session. I do this all the time and it works very well.